# Odd Seg Fault error when scanning lines from a file in C

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I've been working on a program where I need to use C to scan lines from a file and store them in a struct.

My .txt file is in the form:

```
NAME 0.2 0.3
NAME2 0.8 0.1
```

Or in general its a string followed by 2 doubles

My struct is:

```
struct device {
char* name;
double interruptProbability, interruptTime, startTime, endTime;
} myDevice;
```

Now, I'm able to scan the lines in fine, but when it comes time to put them into my struct, something gets messed up.  Here's how I'm doing the scanning:

```
    char line[BUFSIZ];
    while(fgets (line, BUFSIZ, devicesFile) != NULL){
        struct device *d = &myDevice;
        if(!isspace(*line)){
            printf("String: %s \n", &line);
            d->name = "success"; // for testing purposes
            printf("device name before: %s \n", d[0]);
            sscanf(line, "%s %f %f",&d->name, &d->interruptProbability, &d->interruptTime);
            printf("device name after: %s \n", d[0]);
        }
    }
```

When I run this, it'll print off:

```
String: Disk 0.2 0.00005


device name before: success
```

before giving me a seg fault.

I ran GDB to test whats going on with the scan, and for whatever reason it puts in d->name a huge hex number that has (Address out of bounds) next to it.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're overwriting a literal string in the `sscanf` call. `d->name` points to a literal string, and those are read-only and of a fixed length (so if the string you try to get is longer than 7 character you also try to write beyond the end).

You need to either use an array for `d->name` or allocate memory on the heap for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating space for each of your `char *name`. You need to add `d->name = (char *)malloc(<length of the token>*sizeof(char)+1)` before your sscanf call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't scan a string into the pointer `d->name`.

Not even after you assign it a constant value:

```
d->name = "success"; // for testing purposes
```

You need to allocate memory for it, or make it an array.  You should be very careful using `sscanf` to read strings.  It might be better to use `strtok` or just `strchr` to find the first space and then copy the bytes out with `strdup`.

```
char *next = strchr(line, ' ');
if( next != NULL ) {
    *next++ = 0;             // Terminate string and move to next token.
    d->name = strdup(line);  // Make a copy of tokenised string

    // Read the floats - note you should check that the result is equal to 2.
    count = sscanf(next, "%f %f", d->interruptProbability, d->interruptTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sscanf-ing into a string literal. String literals are const char*s in C and C++, are are readonly, so sscanf will crash whilst trying to write to the string literal "success".